# log4j 2 maximum message size using SocketAppender

Tags: log4j2, appender

What is the maximum size of a message supported in SocketAppender of log4j 2?

I am using SocketAppender with TCP protocol to send log message. I wonder if log4j will truncate my message if it exceeds an unknown amount and how to configure it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The socket appender has no maximum size and will not truncate your message.